# Converting UNIX timestamps into pandas datetime taking timezone into account

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I would like to convert the following pandas series containing UNIX timestamps into a pandas datetime using either `to_datetime()` or `arrow` library in Python. I want to set the timezone to UTC and currently it is `Europe/Paris`

For Pandas I am using the following function, but not sure how to take the `Europe\Paris` timezone into account

`pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], unit='s')`

Comment: How is the timezone on a UNIX timestamp Europe/Paris???  Precise definition of Unix time: "number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time, Thursday, 1 January 1970."

Comment: Do you mean that the timestamp is generated using Europe\Paris timezone? for example, "now" timestamp would give a timestamp that is UTC+1.

Comment: Please provide some sample data, and what output you expect and what happens instead. UNIX timestamps **have no other timezone than UTC**, they are simply offsets in seconds from midnight UTC, 01-01-1970. Python's datetime routines take the local timezone into account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], unit='s').astype('datetime64[ns, Europe/Paris]').dt.tz_convert('UTC')
```

Or if versions is lower than 0.24.0, you can use:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], unit='s').dt.tz_localize('Europe/Paris')
s.dt.tz_convert('UTC')
```

Answer (score 4):

#### If you are passing datetime objects that are using Europe\Paris timezone:

Pass `utc=True` when converting, like this:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], unit='s', utc=True)
```

Quoting the `pd.to_datetime()` documentation:

> ```
> utc : boolean, default None
>     Return UTC DatetimeIndex if True (converting any tz-aware
>     datetime.datetime objects as well).
> ```

Or, if like more control, use [`pd.Series.dt.tz_convert()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert.html).

#### If the timestamps are generated using Europe\Paris timezone:

You should convert the timestamp to a native datetime object, localize it using the original timezone (make it timezone aware datetime object), and then convert it to the required timezone.

Like this:

```
# convert timestamp to native datetime
ps = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], unit='s')  # dtype: datetime64[ns]
# localize it to Europe/Paris
ps = ps.dt.tz_localize('Europe/Paris')  # dtype: datetime64[ns, Europe/Paris]
# Finaly, convert to UTC
ps = ps.dt.tz_convert('UTC')  # dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

The difference between `tz_localize` and `tz_convert` is that the first **doesn't move** the time to another time zone, while the second does.

Comment: thanks @Qusai, how will to_datetime know that the time is in Europe/Paris timezone?

Comment: @user308827 directly from the system. Your computers' timezone is set to that timezone, right?

Comment: no this is for an API call. I am in U.S.

Comment: @user308827 well that's strange.. but I guess it's an issue for another question. If my answer solves your issue, kindly accept it :)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it does not really answer my question. I have upvoted your answer though

Answer (score 0):

Suppose That You have Dataset like this,

```
2019-02-02 11:32:46.484236    4
2019-02-03 11:32:46.484236    1
2019-02-04 11:32:46.484236    8
2019-02-05 11:32:46.484236    2
2019-02-06 11:32:46.484236    4
2019-02-07 11:32:46.484236    2
2019-02-08 11:32:46.484236    5
2019-02-09 11:32:46.484236    5
2019-02-10 11:32:46.484236    6
2019-02-11 11:32:46.484236    1
```

Here it's on `'Asia/Kolkata'` timezone.

As per your Question, You need UTC timezone from this.

So, For that First you need to **localize** that, this Dataset belongs to which timezone?.

So, For this.....

```
df = df.tz_localize(tz = 'Asia/Kolkata')
```

it will make **localize** on the name of `'Asia/Kolkata'`.

**Output:**

```
2019-02-02 11:32:46.484236+05:30    4
2019-02-03 11:32:46.484236+05:30    1
2019-02-04 11:32:46.484236+05:30    8
2019-02-05 11:32:46.484236+05:30    2
2019-02-06 11:32:46.484236+05:30    4
2019-02-07 11:32:46.484236+05:30    2
2019-02-08 11:32:46.484236+05:30    5
2019-02-09 11:32:46.484236+05:30    5
2019-02-10 11:32:46.484236+05:30    6
2019-02-11 11:32:46.484236+05:30    1
```

Now You can **convert** your `'Asia/Kolkata'` timezone to UTC.
Like this...

```
df = df.tz_convert(tz = 'UTC')
```

**Output:**

```
2019-02-02 06:02:46.484236+00:00    4
2019-02-03 06:02:46.484236+00:00    1
2019-02-04 06:02:46.484236+00:00    8
2019-02-05 06:02:46.484236+00:00    2
2019-02-06 06:02:46.484236+00:00    4
2019-02-07 06:02:46.484236+00:00    2
2019-02-08 06:02:46.484236+00:00    5
2019-02-09 06:02:46.484236+00:00    5
2019-02-10 06:02:46.484236+00:00    6
2019-02-11 06:02:46.484236+00:00    1
```

You can do same for your `'Europe\Paris'` timezone.